# High CPU usage in the processes related to postgres in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, postgresql, cpu-load

My Ubuntu server 12.04 hangs quite oftenly (say once in a day), after hard reboot it starts running normally.

The server is Intel Xeon having 2 CPUs with 8GB RAM.There is high CPU usage in the processes related to postgres in ubuntu 12.04 (80%, 90% and sometimes more than 100%).

Answer (score 4):

[This post](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/10/debug-postgresql-performance-issues.html) saved my hours.
check for the query running for the longest time and check if the query is stuck and running since more an hour. Run the following command.

```
SELECT max(now() - xact_start) FROM pg_stat_activity
                               WHERE state IN ('idle in transaction', 'active');
```

If this is more than an hour, than this is the issue. Kill the long running connection and limit the max age of the connection from application side.

Answer (score 1):

I googled a very helpful link.
http://frosty-postgres.blogspot.in/2012/08/postgresql-numa-and-zone-reclaim-mode.html
After setting zone_reclaim_mode to 0 ,performace of server has improved.
Queries are taking less time.
Server is still under close observation.